# Does cloud storage replicate the data over many datacenters if so it means i benefit content delivery network?

Tags: storage, replication, cloud-computing, amazon-s3, cdn

Let's assume that i want to use cloud storage service from one of the cloud storage provider, i got X gb structured and unstructured data and i will use this data as my contents of my interactive web page.

And now i have some doubts about this point.I have many users and they are all visiting my web page from various countries.To be more specific first;

does my data stored **only** of the Cloud Storage data center ? or Does my data replicated over many data centers of my provider?

second if so; how can i benefit from content delivery network?
(matching and placing users’ content nearest storage data centers)

Comment: Warner you edited the tags by adding amazon-s3 and i never use it in my context degrades my reputation 24:), funny.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- First question - it depends on what plan you're buying from your provider. Read up on what the offerings are.
- Second question - it depends on what plan you're buying from your provider. This will probably be more costly than the first feature.

Edit - I'll give you a concrete example. [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/#Where_is_my_data_stored) says that your data will be replicated, I assume that means automatic failover if they lose an active site. (Although I would read the details of my SLA if I were buying from them.) They also say that you have to pick your region. So, for Amazon S3, the answers are (1) Yes and (2) No.

But that's just for Amazon S3. Google may have different answers. Azure may have different answers. Rackspace may have different answers. Any of them may have multiple answers based on your checking account. There is no *single answer* for the broad category of "cloud storage.*

Further edit - Amazon has a [beta service called CloudFront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/), that offers a "Yes" to your second question.

Comment: You just put more question marks, i need some useful information. thanks.i haven't seen any kind of provider mentions about their replication policy if so content delivery network option. It is so important that the giant akamai can affect from this property.

Comment: The answer to both questions *is* "it depends". It depends on the provider you're buying from. If you haven't purchased yet, these are questions *to ask the provider you're looking at.* If you have purchased, you need *to research what it is that you bought*. Any cloud provider could have tiered service offerings - one inexpensive offering without HA, a more expensive one with geographically-dispersed HA/DR, and a more-expensive one yet with the geographically-aware tuning you're interested in.

Comment: @Berkay - I have a gentle suggestion. If you weren't able to find these details on Amazon's S3 site (it's the big link on the left, with text that says "FAQs"), I think you need to try harder. I know SF is for both tough and easy questions, but this is stuff that you should really teach yourself - how to learn by reading and researching. Then, once you've gotten a few answers, you'll have further questions, and *those* will probably be great fodder for discussion on this site.

Comment: thanks mfinni, you are right i have to search and doing so.Actually i think that my question is so important for using cloud storage as a content delivery networks.Finally while searching i found a paper "MetaCDN: Harnessing ‘Storage Clouds’ for high performance content delivery" here they build MetaCDN to get benefit from various storage providers all around the world and replicates the data, users are directed to the nearest data replica.This system befeits from many efficient results (cost, bandwidth etc.), mfinni thanks for your precious answers.

Comment: @Berkay - that's a two-year-old academic research paper. Are you asking for an academic reason, or are you actually trying to buy (or build) a service to meet these needs?

Comment: i'm just asking to understand the topic, any kind of proof will be used in my survey which is about advantages of cloud storage, cdn can be one of them. if i can use it and get some results will be better for my survey, of course.

Answer (score 1):

mfinni is so on the money with this one - it really does depend.

**IF** you contact a number of cloud-storage/CDN providers and specifically ask them if they can take your content, replicate it globally and ensure that it's globally load-balanced/delivered to your users from their closest replication point not only will some of them be able to do this but they'll shake your hand very warmly indeed because they will be making a great deal of money from you for this - it's VERY expensive for you if you want this to happen, but they will do it for you if you ask.

Now what I *think* you want to know is will the replicate your data, as mfinni says 'it depends', on the provider and package you choose; will it be global, same answer; will they deliver it from there, almost certainly not by default but 'it depends' on the package you pay for - basically listen to mfinni and speak to various providers.

Comment: ok,if cloud provider doesn't support.As mention in MetaCDN i can find a way to replicate my data among various storage providers and get benefit from CDN using cloud storage providers.

Comment: @Berkay - That doesn't sound as simple or cost-effective as going with a cloud provider that does support global hosting and CDN.

Answer (score 0):

Your data may or may not get replicated to additional datacenters, though this is usually stipulated if true.

To benefit from a CDN, you need to buy CDN services from a provider specifically offering this service, as cloud storage is not the same thing, though it is possible for some CDNs to offer you edge storage, which will replicate your files to multiple locations, and the price will be quite high, as they would be accounting for storing the same 1GB of files in multiple locations, so seeing price tags like 70 cents per GB or more is typical in these conditions.

Comment: ok. actually my goal is using storage providers as a content delivery network.if i can benefit, if it is realize i think it's a kind of evolution in content delivery networks.